# How do I access the category of an entry with Element API?

Tags: json, plugin-elementapi

The category count is only ever 1 and I need to output the name of the category the entry belongs to.

Would there need to be a cross-over between the EntryModel and CategoryModel?

```
'transformer' => function(EntryModel $entry) {
                return [
                    'title' => $entry->title,
                    'url' => $entry->url,
                    'jsonUrl' => UrlHelper::getUrl("jobs/{$entry->id}.json"),
                    'postDate' => $entry->postDate->getTimestamp() * 1000,
                    'id' => $entry->id,
                    'jobOverview' => (string) $entry->jobOverview,
                    'category' => $entry->jobCategory[0],
                ];
            },
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Same as you would access it from a Twig [template](https://craftcms.com/docs/categories-fields#templating).  If you're positive there will always be one category selected, then this would work:

```
'transformer' => function(EntryModel $entry) {
    return [
        'category' => (string)$entry->categoryHandle[0],
    ];
},
```

Comment: yeah, I'd thought I could have done that but nothing comes from it.

Comment: Are you sure you have the correct `$entry`? What do you get if you dump `$entry->categoryHandle[0]` from a normal Twig template?

Comment: Should have clarified, this is for all jobs, not a single entry endpoint. I found that ```'category' => (string) $entry->jobCategory[0],``` works though

Comment: Weird... CategoryModel's `__toString()` magic method should be getting called there.  Regardless, I'll update my answer.